# Получение массива значений чекбоксов в контроллере

Tags: yii2, yii

В форме создания есть такая группа чекбоксов

```
$form->field($model, 'ingredients')->checkboxList(
        ArrayHelper::map($ingredients, 'id', 'name')
    )
```

В html это выглядит как

```
<input name="Dish[ingredients][]" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input name="Dish[ingredients][]" value="2" type="checkbox">
```

Как мне получить массив значений этих чекбоксов в actionCreate контроллера?

Пробую так

```
Yii::$app->request->post('Dish[ingredients]', [])
```

Получаю пустой массив.

Answer (score 1):

```
Yii::$app->request->post()['Dish']
```

Comment: Я сделал так: добавил в модель Dish поле ingredients, и переданные чекбоксы стали доступны через `$model->ingredients`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ingredients = Yii::$app->request->post('Dish')['ingredients'];
```

или

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
$ingredients = $model->ingredients;
```

или

```
$ingredients = $_POST['Dish']['ingredients'];
```